# How can you redirect user from any website to manage chrome extension settings? (Not sure if it possible by JS code)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

We are planning to redirect chrome user from our website to below chrome extension setting.
Let me know if it is possible.

```
chrome://extensions/?id=efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi
```

Trying something like this from my react application. But not working for me.
I know below code need chrome store url but my requirement is to redirect to settings.

Sudo code sample 1:

```
window.open("chrome://extensions/?id=efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi");
```

Sudo code sample 2:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: 'chrome://extensions/?id=efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi',
   active: true
 });
```

Comment: Is there a way to access local resource from react?
Getting error as below: 
`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions/?id=efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi
showSaveMessage @ SystemSettings.tsx:12`

Comment: Are you trying this in your react app or chrome extension. As I used your code of example 2 in my test extension, replaced the extension ID and execute this code on the extension on click event. and it redirecting to my extension's details/setting page

Comment: Hi @DineshPatil, Thanks for replying. I am trying from my react app. My website is in react app. Our extension code is different.

Comment: Hello @rosh_021, this will may help you, https://linuxpip.org/fix-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource/ . Please let us know if you found the answer and post it in the answer section. **I reproduced the same issue and method one helped [menstion in link] in my case.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by adding this peace of code in my Chrome Extension background js. I am able to redirect user to local chrome settings from my React app. (Website)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(onExternalMessage);

function onExternalMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if(request.msg === "redirectLocalChrome"){
   chrome.tabs.create({
     url: 'chrome://extensions/?id=efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi',
     active: true
   });
 }
}
```

My React website contain this peace of code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi", { msg: "redirectLocalChrome" });
```